# Magento - Restrict some catogories for some customer groups

Tags: magento

How can I hide/show some categories for some customers groups in Magento ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what you need:

https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

Why roll your own!?!

Comment: Thanks Mathew, I have installed it, but it seems like it can only hide all categories or products for a specific customer group, but I want to hide only some catogories and not all of them... :( Is there a solution to that ?

Comment: ...did not see the word 'some'! Not sure there is another off the shelf solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had the Netzarbeiter Groups Catalog 2 extension just installed on a new Magento website and I can tell you this is possible.

Just go to the category you want to hide, and after the option 'Hide from Groups' you select the customer groups you want to hide this category for.

Answer (score 2):

ʍǝɥʇɐɯ is correct. However, use version 2 of Customer Groups (https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2). Using this you can restrict Categories to certain customer groups (Products > Manage Categories - "Hide from Groups")